# TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ........ ::__construct() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface, array given, called in

Tags: 9, plugins, dependency-injection

I'm getting an error when I wrote the code using Dependency injection:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\sydneypro_exchange_rates_block\Plugin\Block\ExchangeRatesBlock::__construct() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface, array given, called in /var/www/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/Factory/ContainerFactory.php on line 25 in Drupal\sydneypro_exchange_rates_block\Plugin\Block\ExchangeRatesBlock->__construct() (line 55 of modules/custom/sydneypro_exchange_rates_block/src/Plugin/Block/ExchangeRatesBlock.php).

**ExchangeRatesBlock.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\sydneypro_exchange_rates_block\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a block with Exchange Rates.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "block_exchange_rates",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Exchange rates block"),
 * )
 */
class ExchangeRatesBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * Cache for Data.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface
   */
  protected $cacheBackend;

  /**
   * Guzzle Http Client.
   *
   * @var \GuzzleHttp\Client
   */
  protected $httpClient;

  /**
   * Configuration for module.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig
   */
  protected $config;

  /**
   * ExchangeRatesBlock constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface $cache_backend
   *   The cacheBackendInterface.
   * @param \GuzzleHttp\Client $http_Client
   *   The httpclient.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig $immutable_config
   *   The configuration.
   */
  public function __construct(CacheBackendInterface $cache_backend, Client $http_Client, ImmutableConfig $immutable_config) {
    $this->cacheBackend = $cache_backend;
    $this->httpClient = $http_Client;
    $this->config = $immutable_config;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('cache.default'),
      $container->get('http_client'),
      $container->get('config.factory')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $client = $this->httpClient;
    $access_key = $this->config->get('exchange.settings')->get('exchange_access_key');
    $cid = 'sydneypro_exchange_rates_block';

    try {
      if ($cache = $this->cacheBackend->get($cid)) {
        $data = $cache->data;
      }
      else {
        $response = $client->get('http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=' . $access_key);
        $response_data = $response->getBody();
        $data = json_decode($response_data);
        $this->cacheBackend->set($cid, $data);
      }

      $properties = [
        'uah' => [
          'label' => $this->t('Hryvnia'),
          'value' => round($data->rates->UAH, 2),
        ],
        'usd' => [
          'label' => $this->t('Dollar'),
          'value' => round($data->rates->USD, 2),
        ],
        'gbp' => [
          'label' => $this->t('Pound sterling'),
          'value' => round($data->rates->GBP, 2),
        ],
      ];

      $build = [];

      foreach ($properties as $exchange_property => $data) {
        $build[$exchange_property] = ['#type' => 'container'];
        $build[$exchange_property]['label'] = ['#markup' => $data['label']];
        $build[$exchange_property]['separator'] = ['#markup' => ': '];
        $build[$exchange_property]['value'] = ['#markup' => $data['value']];
      }
      $build[] = [
        '#attached' => [
          'library' => [
            'sydneypro_exchange_rates_block/sydneypro_exchange_rates_block',
          ],
        ],
      ];

      return $build;
    }
    catch (ConnectException $e) {
      return [
        '#markup' => Markup::create('<h1>Internet, DNS, or other connection error</h1>'),
      ];
    }
    catch (RequestException $e) {
      return [
        '#markup' => Markup::create('<h1>Sorry, no data available</h1>'),
      ];
    }
  }

  /**
   * Disable cache for a block because my own cache doesn't work with it.
   *
   * @return int
   *   return cacheMaxAge 0
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }

}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of a class that extends [`Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Plugin%21PluginBase.php/class/PluginBase/9.3.x), such as in your case (as [`Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Block%21BlockBase.php/class/BlockBase/9.3.x) extends that class) receives the following arguments.

- `array $configuration`
- `$plugin_id`
- `$plugin_definition`

That's what that error message means: You defined the first parameter of the constructor to implement `Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface`, but it receives an array.

The `create()` method defined for your block is ignored by Drupal. If you need to pull dependencies from the container, a plugin (such as a block plugin) needs to implement [`ContainerFactoryPluginInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Plugin%21ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php/interface/ContainerFactoryPluginInterface/9.3.x), which is what the [`BookNavigationBlock`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21book%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21BookNavigationBlock.php/class/BookNavigationBlock/9.3.x) class does. (The following is only part of the class code.)

```php
class BookNavigationBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * Constructs a new BookNavigationBlock instance.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match
   *   The current route match.
   * @param \Drupal\book\BookManagerInterface $book_manager
   *   The book manager.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface $node_storage
   *   The node storage.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, RouteMatchInterface $route_match, BookManagerInterface $book_manager, EntityStorageInterface $node_storage) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->routeMatch = $route_match;
    $this->bookManager = $book_manager;
    $this->nodeStorage = $node_storage;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $container->get('current_route_match'), $container->get('book.manager'), $container->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node'));
  }

}
```

In your case, the class should use the following code. (I am showing what needs to be changed in the code shown in the question.)

```php
namespace Drupal\sydneypro_exchange_rates_block\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a block with Exchange Rates.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "block_exchange_rates",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Exchange rates block"),
 * )
 */
class ExchangeRatesBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * ExchangeRatesBlock constructor.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface $cache_backend
   *   The cacheBackendInterface.
   * @param \GuzzleHttp\Client $http_Client
   *   The httpclient.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ImmutableConfig $immutable_config
   *   The configuration.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, CacheBackendInterface $cache_backend, Client $http_Client, ImmutableConfig $immutable_config) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->cacheBackend = $cache_backend;
    $this->httpClient = $http_Client;
    $this->config = $immutable_config;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, 
      $container->get('cache.default'),
      $container->get('http_client'),
      $container->get('config.factory')
    );
  }

}
```